# Parse Markdown that is separated by `#` with regex pattern

Tags: ruby, regex, markdown

I'd like to parse Markdown that is separated by `#` (single hash).
I've been try to that with Ruby.

Below code outputs `["# Bob's markdown header 1\n\nsomething here.\n\n", "#", "# kitty's header 1\n\nmeow.\n\n"]`

```
p \
arrayobj = <<-EOS.scan(/^#[^#]*/m)

# Bob's markdown header 1

something here.

## this is markdown header 2

yeah.

# kitty's header 1

meow.

EOS
```

However what I wanted is below.

```
["# Bob's markdown header 1\n\nsomething here.\n\n## this is markdown header 2\n\nyeah.\n\n", "# kitty's header 1\n\nmeow.\n\n"]
```

In that case, how do you parse the Markdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match a line starting with `#` not followed with another `#` and any amount of subsequent lines that do not start with such a standalone `#` char:

```
.scan(/^#(?!#).*(?:\R(?!#(?!#)).*)*/)
```

See the [Ruby demo online](https://ideone.com/TORjdi).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `#(?!#)` - a `#` not followed with `#`
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\R(?!#(?!#)).*)*` - zero or more consecutive occurrences of:

  - `\R(?!#(?!#))` - any line break sequence (use `\n` for old Ruby versions) that is not followed with a standalone `#`
  - `.*` - the rest of the line.